# waiting for modal response jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to wait for response modal and I have a solution but I don't know if it's the proper way to do :

```
if(car === 'Berline'){
    var modal = $('.mini.suimodal');
    modal.modal('show');
    modal.find('.button').on('click', function(){
        side = $(this).attr('side');
       slot += side;
        console.log(slot);
        changeItem(slot, imgUrl);
        ajaxQuery();
        displayingThings();
    })
}else{
    changeItem(slot, imgUrl);
    ajaxQuery();
    displayingThings();
}
```

After this I must do some ajax queries and displaying things. The only way I found to "wait" for my modal response is to do same operations twice. If my car is "Berline" I have to chose the side but if the car is not one there is no modal coming. I feel like this is not the best way to go because I'm writing same things, would you have some hints?

Thanks you

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand - It seems like you could probably put your click handler on the modal itself, instead of finding the button in it, so you don't have to create a new one for each type. Also, you could make the bits you're re-writing into a function so you're not re-writing them.

Comment: When I chose a "Berline" car I got a modal. For other one I do not have a modal. This modal contains two buttons "Left" "Right" that's why I chose to put my click handler on buttons instead of the modal itself. I'm going to re-write in a function thanks.

Comment: You can still make a click handler that listens on the modal itself, and just looks at the `event.target` from the event (which is passed to the function() callback), and finds which button was clicked. Event bubbling can be your friend :)